# The lightest way to know if 2 arrays are different?

Tags: perl

Without using Array::Utils, I'm looking for a shorter code just to know if 2 arrays are different (just one value or more, or number of elements).

Comment: use case : many many elements, very long strings ....    
array_diff() would be heavy

Comment: Use Data::Dumper on each or freeze from the Storable module then a simple eq test will prove if they are the same or different.

Comment: thanks, but this piece of code will run in a bigger Perl program several times a week in batch mode ....

Comment: Do you consider them different if they contain the same elements in a different order?

Answer (score 2):

It depends a lot on what you mean by different. For example, consider the following scalars:

- A scalar containing the signed integer `0`.
- A scalar containing the unsigned integer `0`.
- A scalar containing the floating point number `+0`.
- A scalar containing the floating point number `-0`.
- A scalar containing the string `0` (stored using the UTF8=0 format).
- A scalar containing the string `0` (stored using the UTF8=1 format).
- A scalar containing both the string `0` (stored using the UTF8=0 format) and the signed integer `0`.
- A scalar containing both the string `a` (stored using the UTF8=0 format) and the signed integer `0`.

Array elements can be any of these. Which of these should be considered the same, and which should be considered different? (`==` considers them all the same, and `eq` considers all by the last the same.)

The following sub considers an undefined scalar to be different than a defined one, and it considers a scalar to be different than another one if their `eq` considers them different.

```
sub compare_arrays {
   my ($x, $y) = @_;
   return 0 if @$x != @$y;

   for (0..$#$x) {
      if (defined($x->[$_])) {
         return 0 if $x->[$_] ne $y->[$_];
      } else {
         return 0 if !defined($y->[0]);
      }
   }

   return 1;
}
```

Comment: as I said, if a little thing is different, eg :  
("a", "b", "c") is not different from ("a", "c", "b"), but differs from ("b", "c") or ("a", "c", "c")

Comment: So you're saying order is unimportant? Just sort them first.

Comment: Of course, if you've got a large set of unordered strings, using an array might not make as much sense as using a hash. (Store the strings as keys of the elements. The values don't matter. If you can have duplicates, the value can be a count.)

Comment: i could sort, turn to scalar (so a huge string as result) and just compare the two final huge strings .. not so light because of sort - i think about somethind like a light checksum on the two (untouched) arrays and just compare the 2 results

Comment: You have it all backwards. Building a huge string or calculating checksums require processing every character of every string. If you have tons of long strings like you say, this is bad! sort + the code I posted doesn't need to do that. And if you're going to process the entire string using a hash or trie or similar makes more sense than a checksum.

Comment: Ah, it treats all strings as 0 in numeric context. But why doesn't this produce a warning?

Comment: @Holli, Re "*it treats all strings as 0 in numeric context.*", If it doesn't look like a number, yes. ///  Re "*why doesn't this produce a warning?*", It does. `Argument "0a" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==)`

Comment: To be clear, the last item in the list doesn't return to `a0` or `0a`, but to `$x` after `my $x = "a";  0+$x;`

Comment: sometimes .... you update a code which is not yours, and here I can't change all the lines :(

Comment: My solution doesn't involve changing any existing code

Answer (score 0):

Let me offer the next piece of code for this purpose

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use feature 'say';

my %hash;

my $count   = 0;
my $flag    = 1;

while( $flag ) {
    $count++;

    no warnings;                        # suppress warnings temporary

    my @array_1 = split ' ', <DATA>;
    my @array_2 = split ' ', <DATA>;

    use warnings;                       # enable warnings once more

    if( @array_1 == 0 or @array_2 == 0 ) {
        $flag = 0;
        say "It seems we are done";
        next;
    }

    say "Array set # $count";

    if( @array_1 !=  @array_2 ) {
        say "\t - have different size"; # array have different size
        next;
    }

    @hash{@array_1} = @array_2;

    my $same = 1;                       # for now assume that all elements are same

    while( my($k,$v) = each %hash ) {
        $same = 0 if $k != $v;          # well now we know that the elements are different
    }

    say "\t - elements are " . ($same ? "same" : "different");
}

__DATA__
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
21 22 23 24 25 27 26 28 29 30
```